# Exploding file size and sculpting lag problem… Did i do something wrong?

Tags: sculpting

First of all, i have to say i’m quite new to the use of blender, so i apologize already if my question sounds stupid to the hears of some of you.

I’m following this tutorial to improve my understanding of the sculpting tool of blender: https://youtu.be/KsDe1V9Dl-0?t=2220

Everything worked fine until the moment i remeshed my basic shapes of the head of the character (something around 0.015 to be precise). the instructor seems to continue to work with a smooth workflow, but on my side it became super laggy and slow. The file size is now around 450 MB, wich is much more than my other modest blender files.
at the end of the tutorial, he is using vertex paint, wich seems, once again to run smooth on his computer. On my side, i have to wait after each brush stroke to see the result, wich is completely pulling me out of it.

so my question is : did i corrupt the file in some way ( maybe doing something wrong with that remesh step, somehow ?)
Is the blender file size normal because of the number of polygons or does it seems strange ?
And last one : could my config be too cheap for such a work ? (AMD Ryzen 5 / Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660 / 16GB RAM)

I’m hadding a view of my workspace if it may help.
[image]
[image]

Thanks already for your attention and answers

Answer (score 2):

We can see in the screenshot, in the bottom right corner, that the Tris count of your model is a whopping 7 million. That's a very big amount of triangles and explains why blender is lagging and the file is big. Try remeshing with less resolution (bigger voxel size of you're using voxel remesh). If you have the file pre-remesh use that one, cause it will take longer to remesh a model with so many triangles.